# "Pending developer action" is still up, even after I have filled in the requirements

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-search-console

I fixed (or think I fixed) all the requirements for the OAuth google signin to put it into production. I got an email saying that when i am done i should reply to the email and I did.

Yet I have no respone. Its been a week..

Down below are screens of requirements:
[image: 1st part of the email]

[image: 2nd part of the email]

Am I missing something? Or am i simply not understanding all of this? Please let me know

I tried fixing the requirements.

- I made a youtube video regarding the usage of the scopes.
- I added google privacy policies on my privacy page.
- I deleted all credentials in google console
- changed the branding in google console

Comment: Provided that you successfully completed all required modifications, you must wait for Google to approve the changes and respond. Typically that is several business days but can be **much longer** depending on workload. Another option is to make a small change that does affect anything and resubmit just incase your other request was overlooked. However, that will restart the time period.

Comment: Stack Overflow advice: 1) Do not post images of text. Read this [link](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code). 2) Questions regarding a vendor's support policies are off-topic. Read this [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions-on-stack-overflow) Some of the reasons are that we do not have access to your account, nor can we make decisions or take action. You must interact directly with the vendor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting an app in production, and submitting it for verification are two different things.

If you just put the app in production by clicking the button on the consent screen then you should not have gotten this email.  If you did please let me know.

If you did in fact submit the application for verification then it is true there are a number of hurdles that you must first complete and the process is faster if you complete them all before you submit the request for verification.

1. make sure to delete any redirect uri that are not on our domain.
2. make sure all the redirect uris are https
3. make sure to include privacy policy and privacy page on your domain. in english and the language of your app.
4. make sure your domain has been verified in google webmasters.
5. when recording the video make sure that the consent screen and url bar are visible and point to your production domain.  Also make sure the consent screen is in English's.
6. you should ideally have max one client id for each type that you are using.
7. make sure the name of your app does not include any name that could be considered a google product.  Awesome gmail app for example would not pass.

Depending upon the scopes you are using it can take some time but normally not more then a week or two before you hear from them.

Once all that is done submit it for verification.   These are the main hurdles that I have seen my clients face over the last serval years with regard to google verification.